# Is the following syntax `customObject.decoratorFunction` valid according to the decorator spec

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-next

I'm looking at the [ES decorator proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/#sec-syntax) and it defines the following syntax using the grammar:

```
Decorator:
    @ DecoratorMemberExpression
    @ DecoratorCallExpression

DecoratorMemberExpression:
    IdentifierReference
    DecoratorMemberExpression . IdentifierName

DecoratorCallExpression:
    DecoratorMemberExpression Arguments
```

Can anyone please confirm that I understood that grammar correctly and the following expressions are valid according to the spec:

```
@decoratorFunction                       // IdentifierReference
@customObject.decoratorFunction          // IdentifierReference . IdentifierName
@decoratorFunction(...)                  // IdentifierReference Arguments
@customObject.decoratorFunction(...)     // IdentifierReference . IdentifierName Arguments
```

Comment: Yes, that looks ok.

Comment: @Bergi, great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, `DecoratorMemberExpression` allows to use dot notation for property accessors.

This means that this is valid:

```
@customObject.decoratorFunction(...)
```

While this is not:

```
@customObject['decoratorFunction'](...)
```